# What is wxPython doing to the locale to makes pandas crash?

Tags: python, pandas, wxpython

When I try to import pandas into my wxPython application a "ValueError: unknown locale: en-US" exception is thrown.  I can avoid this by importing pandas before the application starts, but that seems like a silly requirement.

This is easily repeatable in a simple wx app:

```
import wx


class TestApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        import pandas

        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, size=wx.Size(670,670), title='Test App')
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.frame.SetSizer(self.sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TestApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I run this app from my virtual environment I get this stack trace:

```
(test) PS env_test> python .\test2.py                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    app = TestApp()
  File ".\test2.py", line 8, in __init__
    import pandas
  File "E:\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
  File "E:\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .tslibs import (
  File "E:\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .conversion import localize_pydatetime, normalize_date
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\c_timestamp.pxd", line 7, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\c_timestamp.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.c_timestamp
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\tzconversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\offsets.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\ccalendar.pyx", line 13, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.ccalendar
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 625, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 530, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.TimeRE.__init__
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 405, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.LocaleTime.__init__
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 362, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime._getlang
  File "c:\python37\lib\locale.py", line 587, in getlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "c:\python37\lib\locale.py", line 495, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: en-US
```

I'm running a virtual environment on Windows 10 using python3.7.4 with minimal packages installed:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
numpy           1.18.4
pandas          1.0.3
Pillow          7.1.2
pip             20.1
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2020.1
setuptools      46.1.3
six             1.14.0
wheel           0.34.2
wxPython        4.1.0
```

I can import pandas outside of the app just fine:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame()
>>>
```

I'm flummoxed, and I've been unable to find answers elsewhere.  Other pandas "unknown locale" errors seem to be related to not having the locale exported on OSX.

Comment: python 3.6 doesn't appear to have the same issue, not that that is a solution but maybe a work around.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, it was working in earlier versions of WX for sure.  I've posted this same question on the wxPython development forum.  That's probably a more appropriate place for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your locale back to the default setting with [setlocale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) right after you initialize the wx.App instance. In most environments, this seems to fix the locale problems caused by wxpython in the rest of your code, and you can continue to use wxpython 4.1.

If you continue to have trouble, see [this discussion](https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/wxpython4-1-windows-python3-7-strptime-locale-issue/34671) about subclassing wx.App

```
app = wx.App(False)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that downgrading wxpython to version 4.0.7 will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I definitely had the program working  with earlier versions of WX.  I've downgraded for now.  Hopefully this gets resolved.

Comment: I was working on version 4.1.0 and I had the same issue. Downgrading to 4.0.7 solved the problem. Thank you @john

Answer (score 1):

It is more like related to locale with wxpython, I got same exception when run locale.getlocale() inside wx app, no issue when run outside wx app.

When downgrade to 4.0.7 the error is gone, so for sure there is new change on 4.1.0 with restrict check on locale or even encoding UTF-8.